# Pairwise dependent random walk recurrent

Tags: pr.probability

Let $\{D_i\}_{i=0,1,2,\dots }$ be independent $\exp(1)$ random variables. We use the collection $\{D_i\}$ to define a random walk on $\mathbb Z$ by $S_0 = 0$ and $S_n = \sum_1^n X_i$ with $X_i \in \{-1,0,1\}$ given by
$$X_i = \mathbf 1 \{ D_{i} > 2 D_{i+1} \} - \mathbf 1 \{ D_{i+1} > 2 D_{i } \}.$$
I am interested in showing $S_n$ visits 0 infinitely often a.s. The pairwise dependence between $X_i$ and $X_{i+1}$ is making this (frustatingly) difficult.

The assumption that $D_i \sim \exp(1)$ is just for convenience and should not be important.

Comment: The expected value of $X_i$ is not zero.  Birkhoff's ergodic theorem implies that $S_n$ goes off to infinity almost surely.

Comment: Mixed up my inequalities. The expected value of X_i should be 0 and I think my latest edit makes it so.

Comment: Ok.  Now $X_i$ can be $0$ you should fix that too.

Comment: Your summands have the property of 1-dependence: if $|i-j|>1$, then $X_i$ and $X_j$ are independent. There are CLT for 1-dependent random variables. The events that $\limsup S_n=\infty$ and $\liminf S_n=-\infty$ are tail events, and therefore have probability 0 or 1 by Kolmogorov's 0-1 law. It's not hard to see the probability is not 0.

Comment: Thanks. http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077475030) houses a classical paper about m-dependent CLT's. Does Kolmogorov's 0-1 law have an analogue for 1-dependent random variables? The statement I am familiar with only covers independent random variables.

Comment: In this case you can just apply the Kolmogorov 0-1 law for the sequence $D_i$, since the events are also tail events for that sequence.

Answer (score 5):

If I remove a summand $X_n$ at regular intervals, then the increments become independent. More concretely, let's introduce $Y_1=X_1+X_2$, $Y_2=X_4+X_5$ etc. and write
$$
S_{3n}=\sum_{j=1}^n Y_j + \sum_{j=1}^n X_{3j} .
$$
Both sums now have iid summands, so the [law of the iterated logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm) applies to both: On a probability $1$ set, we have that $\sum Y_j \approx \pm \sigma_Y \sqrt{2n\ln\ln n}$ for infinitely many $n$. Since $\sigma_X<\sigma_Y$ and the law of the iterated logarithm applies to $\sum X_{3j}$ as well, this second sum can't change the sign of $S_{3n}$. Thus for either sign $\pm$, there are arbitrarily large $n$ for which $S_{3n}$ takes this sign.

Comment: Am I mistaken to believe it isn't obvious that $\sigma_X < \sigma_Y$? The variables $X_1, X_2$ are negatively correlated. I suppose the same argument works when $\sigma_X > \sigma_Y$, but fails if the two are equal.

Comment: @mathjunge: No, it's not obvious (I was lazy), but I think it's strongly expected. Also, the argument is very robust; I could also make the blocks defining $X$ or $Y$ longer. Anyway, I did the calculation now: $\sigma^2_X=2/3$ and $P(Y=2)=1/15$, which contributes $4/15$ to $\sigma^2_Y=EY^2$, as does the event $Y=-2$, so to verify that $\sigma_Y>\sigma_X$, I now need that $P(Y=1)>1/15$, which is easy to check.

Answer (score 3):

An old theorem of Atkinson [Recurrence of co-cycles and random walks, J. London
Math. Soc. (2) 13 (1976), 486–488. MR0419727] states that for sums of stationary $\mathbb Z$-valued random variables with a finite first moment recurrence is equivalent to vanishing of the expectation.